# marshalling converts special characters as question marks

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, bytearrayoutputstream

In my code I want to write some fields to an xml file.

When I call `Marshaller.marshal(element, out);` th correct fields for example a field with value= "barça" will be converted in the ByteArrayOutputStream as bar??a.

Any ideas what could cause this?

I have set this as properties of the marshaller:

```
Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,true
Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING,"UTF-8"
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: sorry, this was a typo

Comment: Well, ç becomes the octet sequence `c3 a7` in UTF-8 and it is probably fair to assume that JAXB isn't broken. How are you inspecting the `ByteArrayOutputStream`? Are you sure the characters are not corrupted prior to being passed to JAXB?

Comment: I debugged the whole thing, and before i to the marshalling, the element is correct, so with the ç. But after the marshalling the out contains the wrong value so with the ??... So something is wrong in the marshal method

Comment: How are you outputting the resultant data?

Comment: final byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
String xml = new String(data);

Comment: Use `new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` or equivalent.

Comment: perhaps, when i make the string i should fill in the charset?

Comment: ok thanks, i'll try. i was just typing the same thing